# How to Redirect between two GWT modules?

Tags: gwt, servlets, redirect, module, web.xml

My project contain two modules. 
a. UserRegistration
b. UserViewProfile

In UserRegistration Module, i have taken details from user and will insert into database. Hear UserRegistrationImpl will generate one ID for each user & attached to session. as well as it send confirmation to UserRegistration client program that details are inserted. so that Userregistration Client will redirect to UserViewProfile Module which will access Common ID from session, and based on that it will retrieve data from database to show details to user. I am using latest GWT version.

while redirecting, i am facing servlet  reference problem in web.xml.
showing error like:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: //userviewpath/userview
```

see my code:

```
#UserRegistrationImpl#
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
System.out.println("s1:"+session);
session.setAttribute("SessionId", newId);
status="pass";
returnId.add(status);
returnId.add(Integer.toString(newId));

#UserRegistration#
if (result.get(0).equals("pass")) {
int addedID=Integer.parseInt(result.get(1));
String url=URLUtils.getRedirectURL("/UserViewProfile.html");
Window.Location.replace(url);
} else if (result.equals("fail")) {
dialogBox1.setWidget(Unotsuccesslbl);
#UserRegistrationInterface#
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("userreg")
public interface UserRegistrationInterface extends RemoteService 
{
ArrayList<String> addRegistrationDetails(UserRegDetails userDetails)throws 
IllegalArgumentException;
}
#UserViewProfileImpl#
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
System.out.println("s2 val:"+session.getAttribute("AyushId")); 
//userViewProfile need  this Id value
#UserViewProfileInterface#
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("userview")
public interface UserViewProfileInterface extends RemoteService 
ArrayList<String> GetProfileDetails(ArrayList<String> userProfileArray)
throws IllegalArgumentException;{}
#web.xml#
<!-- User Registration part start-->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>UserRegistrationImpl</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.testegg.ayushcare.server.UserRegistrationImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UserRegistrationImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/userregpath/userreg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- User Registration part end-->
<!-- UserViewProfile part start -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>UserViewProfileImpl</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.testegg.ayushcare.server.UserViewProfileImpl
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UserViewProfileImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/userviewpath/userview</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- UserViewProfile part end -->
```

Comment: check it contains two backward slash character "\\" in url prefix somehow. it should be one.